# pauseApp Java ME

Tags: java, java-me, midp

what actions should be taken in the pauseApp method of a Java ME midlet. what is the purpose of having this method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This](http://www.developer.com/java/j2me/article.php/10934_1561591_1) is a pretty good description. Say you are writing a Tetris game, you would stop the brick from falling when paused. On a phone, interruptions happen and resources are limited, so you need to write your code to accommodate them.

Comment: I'd like to add by saying that there are a lot of devices that simply ignore the spec and don't call this when they should. If you're working with Canvas you'd be better off using the showNotify()/hideNotify mechanism which works well on every device i've ever tested (a wide variety).

Answer (score 0):

[Midlet javadoc](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr037/javax/microedition/midlet/MIDlet.html#pauseApp()) tells us that this method is called when the application is set in paused mode. Paused mode corresponds to the event of the user pausing the application, or the application being paused by something more urgent, like a phone call.

Comment: user pausing the application how?

Comment: many phones allow the user to pause a java app, for example on my phone if I press the return button, my phone is back to the main screen, and the application is paused (but not stopped)

Answer (score 0):

its purely depends on your task and requirement.

Each and every application will have its own steps while resuming the application

For Example if we are using videoplayer and as soon it gets interupted via phone call or bluetooth we must save mediaTime and write some functionality stuff in pauseApp
Once app tries to resume we must startApp with that particular MediaTime where it has stopped

Same is scenario for gaming thing , need to store some info in pauseApp and use them once again in StartAPP.